# How to store the value of particular button clicked event of data list in a session?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, datalist

I am showing my data in data list using grid view each grid view includes a button click how how can I store a particular button click value in a session and redirect the value to next page

```
protected void DataList1_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "Button2")
            {
                Response.Redirect("movers_packers_profile.aspx?sp_id=" + e.CommandArgument.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is it redirecting to the next page now? What data you need to pass to next page?

Comment: Yes it is redirecting to next page I want to pass value(sp_id) that has been obtained by Eval function from database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check whether your button is set like this

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="Button2" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "sp_id")%>' />
```